# snowflake_connector_python-2.7.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue, python-3.9

When I am running AWS GLUE with Python 3.9 and using snowflake Connector .whl file name: snowflake_connector_python-2.7.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl , it throws error filename.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Please suggest as I tried multiple snowflake connectors files compatible with Python version 3.9

Comment: You say that you've  tried multiple snowflake connectors files compatible with Python version 3.9, but in the wheel example you've provided you are trying to use the Python connector using Python 2.7.4 version. Additionally, Python 2.7.4 is available up to Glue version 2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.